# Running sub within sub (in a loop) causes textbox TabKeyBehavior to not work properly, ie = False

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, tabcontrol

When dynamically creating textboxes/comboboxes on a userform, I create  a combobox with information in another Excel workbook. (Not in the workbook I created the code/userform in. Nor can it be because it may change/get issued in the future & I don't want to have to move code into it).

After I create the combobox, I call another sub, Populate_Steel_List, to populate it. After everything has been generated, when tabbing through the textboxes/comboboxes actual Tab values are being placed in the textboxes/comboboxes, instead of moving on to the next textbox/combobox on the userform!

If I comment out calling for Populate_Steel_List, the userform's tabbing works fine. So I know calling it is causing the problem.

I tried adding a For-Next (For Each-Next as well) loop for each control, setting the `.TabKeyBehavior = False`. It didn't seem to do anything.

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub NumberMembers_Change()

' ....there is some other code in this sub, but has been tested,
' ie. commented out, till I found out 
' where the offending code actually is

Dim TextBox8 As Object ' have also tried As Control; both run fine,
'                        but neither fix TabKeyBehavior on the userform

' Create Member Cross Section List Textboxes
Set TextBox8 = Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
With TextBox8
    .Name = "MemberSectionList" & i
    .height = 17
    .Width = 90
    .Left = 494
    .Top = 20 * i
    .TabIndex = NextTabNumber + 3
End With
TextBox8Name(i) = TextBox8.Name
MembSectCurrBox = TextBox8.Name
Populate_Steel_List 'If I comment this out, the problem goes away,
' but that's not gonna work

End Sub

' ...and here's the code for Populate_Steel_List

Private Sub Populate_Steel_List()

Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
'Dim TextFile As Integer

' Check to see if log file has already been created
' Skip to using the path to find the excel document to have VBA read from it
If Len(FilePathToAISCShapesDatabase) > 0 Then GoTo Skip 

If FilePathToAISCShapesDatabase = vbNullString Then
    ChDir (Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ActiveWorkbook.Name, ""))
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        ' Set the title of the dialog box.
        .Title = "Please select the latest AISC shapes database file."
        ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
        .Filters.Clear
        .InitialFileName = "AISC Shapes Database v14.1.xlsm"
        .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsm, *.xlsx"
        .Filters.Add "Excel 97–Excel 2003", "*.xls"
        If .Show = True Then
            FilePathToAISCShapesDatabase = .SelectedItems(1) 
            'Now I have the filepath to the AISC Shapes Database
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    ' Create textfile in this location:
    ' Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "AISCListLoc.txt"
    'Open the text file
    Open DirFile For Output As #1
    'Write some lines of text
    Print #1, FilePathToAISCShapesDatabase
    'Save & Close Text File
    Close #1
End If

Skip:
' Read from file that you have path to
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Workbooks.Open (FilePathToAISCShapesDatabase)

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets("Database v14.1").Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
Me.Controls(MembSectCurrBox).List = rng.value
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set rng = Nothing
AppActivate ThisWorkbook.Application

Dim i ' Not sure if I really need to have this here or not;
'       I also added it in the UserForm_Initialize(), 
'        but adding it doesn't seem to help

For i = 1 To Me.Controls.Count
    If TypeName(Me.Controls(i - 1)) = "Textbox" Then
        Me.Controls(i - 1).TabKeyBehavior = False
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

`TextBox8Name(i)` is a private variant I used to keep track of how many comboboxes get generated (for limitations of an FEA program down the road).

`FilePathToAISCShapesDatabase` is a global string (in the module) so the user doesn't always have to point to the AISC shapes spreadsheet after the first time.

I tried not to select anything while in the other workbook, AISC Shapes Database v14.1.xlsm, but maybe I messed up?

Comment: Welcome.  The friendly sentiment is appreciated, but it does clutter up your question and may make it harder to get good answers. Consider sticking to just the facts and the question.

Comment: sorry; didnt mean to make things wordy...